# Chrome dev tools loses network history

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The Network tab in Google Chrome developer tools is great but seems to lose all history on certain form posts.

Is there any way to get it to retain network history?

If not is there another tool I could use?

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshed from the server end"? Your browser does not expose any network-accessible APIs to refresh the page at the remote server's will. I might be misunderstanding the situation, though.

Comment: Not sure exactly what I mean to be honest - on some form posts the browser seems to completely refresh - almost like it gets redirected.  I have updated my question to reflect.

Comment: Does the "Preserve Log upon Navigation" status bar button in the `Network` panel (the black circle) help?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov thank you for pointing that out. It completely solves the problem. Should be on by default. If you add this as an answer I will award. Thanks again!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The "Preserve Log upon Navigation" status bar button in the `Network` panel should solve the issue:

[image]

Comment: Just to let everyone know - this setting preserves the request history but not the response history. I think this is probably a bug.

Comment: Two years later, and it still doesn't preserve the response history.

Comment: -1 for it do not solve all the problems. But not all of them. Event if i checked "Preserve Log upon Navigation", I still lost request form data of some request in some case. I think I need charles to finish my job. The `Network` panel just throw those data. (verified with chrome 62 in 2017-11-22).

Comment: And today it's not working... you can check this in firefox, it's really useful to debug ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get it to retain network history?

Yes and No. It may not retain the network history you want. (verified with chrome 62 in 2017-11-22)

> If not is there another tool I could use?

https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Charles is an HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between their machine and the Internet. This includes requests, responses and the HTTP headers (which contain the cookies and caching information).

Comment: What about Fiddler and Burp?

Comment: @Alex78191 Sorry,I do not try them,I only try charles.

Answer (score 0):

I am using chrome 98 and this worked for me checking this

[image]