# ActionLink controller is getting called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a table view with list of roles and an action link to create new roles. Below is my roles.cshtml page

```
@model List<ExpenCare.Models.CompanyRole>

<div class="row">
@Html.Partial("_RightSidePane")
<div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-md-10">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-Roles-Content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-Roles"></div>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("UpdateRoles", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Enable
                    </th>
                </tr>

                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Enabled, new { @checked = "checked" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Save Changes" /></p>
            <p style="color:green; font-size:12px;">@ViewBag.Message</p>
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Create new Roles", "ViewCreateRoles", "Admin", null, new { id = "CreateRoles", @class = "appao-btn" })
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

"Create new roles" button calls to ViewCreateRoles method in admin controller, which stated below.

```
public ActionResult ViewCreateRoles()
{
   return View("Roles/CreateRoles");
}
```

In CreateRoles.cshtml page user can create a role and submit. when submitting it redirects to action CreateRoles in the same admin controller.

```
@model ExpenCare.Models.CompanyRole

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateRoles";
}

<div class="row">
    @Html.Partial("_RightSidePane")
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-md-10">
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-Profile-Content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-Profile">

                @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateRoles", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Enabled, "Enable", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Enabled)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the CreateRoles methodin admin controller.

```
public ActionResult CreateRoles(CompanyRole role)
        {
            List<CompanyRole> roles;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1888/api/");
            var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync("CompanyRoles", role);
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<CompanyRole>>();
                readTask.Wait();

                roles = readTask.Result;
                return View("Roles/Roles", model: roles);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "not updated.";
                return View("Roles/CreateRoles");
            }

        }
```

After creating a role on success user is redirecting to roles.cshtml mentioned above which shows all the roles. My problem is that my process of adding a role (go to roles page-> create new role-> redirect to roles page) is working fine. But just after redirecting to the roles page I get "An exception of type 'System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException' occurred in ExpenCare.dll but was not handled in user code" error in my web api which is getting called in CreateRoles. when I debug the process I see that after going to "Dispose" method of admin contoller "CreateRoles" method is getting called again and null "CompanyRole role" data is passed to the web API. I dunno how it is getting called again. I checked in google and tried removing all "#" from href and src of my view and layout pages, but it is still not working. I can't find why the same method is getting called twice without the button click.

Comment: Sounds like your form is getting posted twice somewhere. Just at first glance I notice you're returning `ViewResult`s from your post method, which could lead to issues. Check out the [P/R/G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, which can help prevent users from posting a form twice. Other than that I don't see anything that should be double-posting. Do you have any Javascript that could be interfering?

Comment: As @MickelsonMichael has mentioned you should follow PRG pattern. Otherwise, you need to clear model state [ModelState.Clear();] before calling : return View('....')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13420369/34092 is your friend.